# Is it possible to use the possessive pronoun "whose" for things that are not human being?

Tags: usage, relative-clauses, possessives

So far I came across cases that the usage of the possessive pronoun "whose" refer to human being. For instance:

> "The man **whose** horse was strongest, won the competition".

Then my question is if it's possible to use the determiner "whose" for things that are not human being, it means for inanimate things.

For instance:

> The pan **whose** lid is transparent, is now now on the stove."

n.b. I saw the claim that it's a duplicate of another question here on ELL but as well as the question there is not clear as you can see, also the answers are not clear and actually after I read there the answers I didn't really succeeded to understand what is the answer for my question.

Comment: The question there along with the answers there look unorganized at all.

Comment: Snailplane's accepted answer there addresses your question precisely.

Comment: Then simply the answer is positive:  it's possible to use the possessive-pronoun "whose" for things that are not human being / for inanimate things. Thank you.